# reconnect after explicitly sendign a logout

Tags: java, quickfixj

Does quickfixj try to reconnect on a session on which an explicit logout has been sent.

I have asked about it and have been told that it does not but I want to confirm.

What should be done for reconnection in such case? All possible solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the QuickfixJ config you can see this flag

> **ReconnectInterval**   Time between reconnection attempts in seconds. Only used for initiators

So the initiator will try on the intervals to reconnect. The acceptor doesn't do that and shouldn't ever do that.

Comment: i have been told that if one explicitly uses logout to logout of a sessions then qfixj does not do reconnect for it. i need advice on what to do for reconnect in such case.

Comment: Clarification, logout and reconnect are different things. You are confusing them. Logout is for a session and Reconnect is for establishing a socket connection(setting up a session).

Comment: i understand the difference. i seek advice on how to do reconnection logic your self when you have lost the qfixjs reconnections feature by using logout.